# Getting the right sign when calculating repeated sign switches in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to simulate a grid of spins in python that can change their orientation (represented by the sign):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> spin_values = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (2, 2))
>>> spin_values
array([[-1,  1],
       [ 1,  1]])
```

I then throw two sets of random indices of that grid for spins that have a certain probability to switch their orientation, let's say:

```
>>> i = np.array([1, 1])
>>> j = np.array([0, 0])
>>> switches = np.array([-1, -1])
```

i and j here contain the indices that might change and switches states whether they do switch (-1) or keep their orientation (1). My idea for calculating the new orientations was:

```
>>> spin_values[i, j] *= switches
```

When a spin orientation only changes once this works fine. However, when it is supposed to change twice (as with the example values) it only changes once, therefore giving me a wrong result.

```
>>> spin_values
array([[-1,  1],
       [-1,  1]])
```

How could I get the right results while having a short run time (this has to be done many times on a bigger grid)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the count of unique pairs of indices and compute `-1 ** n`:

```
idx, cnt = np.unique(np.vstack([i, j]), axis=1, return_counts=True)
spin_values[tuple(idx)] = (-1) ** cnt
```

Updated `spin_values`:

```
array([[-1,  1],
       [ 1,  1]])
```

Comment: It might be that a spin does not flip. That information is stored in switches. How can I make it work using that array instead of the (-1) you used here?